# User.Identity.Name is null for Blazor Wasm hosted in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

User.Identity.Name is null for Blazor Wasm hosted in asp.net core.
There is no such claim as name or email. I'm using default template of Visual Studio.

`services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();`

`services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();`

Am I missing something?

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been struggling with the same issue for few months already. After try many approaches, finally I come out with the solution.

```
using System.Linq;

services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, 
   ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
   {
       opt.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("name");
       opt.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("name");
   });

services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

Please let me know if this solve the issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue in an API controller I added to my Blazor WASM hosted server project. Adding this to my `program.cs` file is what fixed it for me:

`services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/17517

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make any real sense. You don't host IdentityServer inside a blazor application, instead you have a separate dedicated services that implements OpenIDConnect and that can authenticate users and give out tokens.

In a blazor application you typically have this type of skeleton to configure authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(opt =>
   //Add configuration here
{
}).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
   //Add configuration here
});
```

See this article for details:
[How do I implement Blazor authentication with OpenID Connect?](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazo/general/how-do-i-implement-blazor-authentication-with-openid-connect)

Comment: Blazor Wasm is hosted inside of ASP.NET Core Web API and this server has IdentityServer inside. (I'm not sure about that, but it is implied by the resources I read on msdn)

Comment: Also I haven't the skeleton presented by you.

Comment: I would still put IdentityServer in a separate ASP.NET core service, because it will be much harder to reason and troubleshoot it from my experience.  I really like the separation of concerns is an important rule here. Because as a developer you really need to understand what is going on.